# Use of 'in pair' or 'in group' in a sentence

Tags: phrases, vocabulary, word-order

I am really confused about this case now since I can't find a satisfying answer with Google. It is a minor case, but still, I want to understand it better. Please tell me which of the following are the correct ones:

1. Fadli and Sandy always work in pairs/in pair/in a pair?
2. Rahmi and Eza investigated the case in groups/in group/in a group

*note: both pair and group are singular in those contexts.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use the phrase 'in pairs' and 'in groups' to state the type of activity.
For example:
The teacher asked them to work in pairs/ in groups (of three, of four, etc).

What you want to say might be
"Fadli and Sandy did their pair work."
or
"Fadli always does his school work with Sandy"

Comment: did their pair work?!?   No.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of 'pair' is: "a set of two things used together or regarded as a unit."

Thus, for the first example I don't think you can use 'in pairs' as Fadli and Sandy are not separate pairs. They're one pair (only two people), and thus you could use:

> "Fadli and Sandy always work as a pair." or "Fadli and Sandy always work in a pair."

For the second example I think the same situation applies.

> "Rahmi and Eza investigated the case as a group."

I think the phrase 'in a group' would only be appropriate if the two people were part of a group of larger people, and you were singling them out.